# My git branch on github should be only 2 ahead but it is also 2 behind

Tags: git, version-control, github, branch, git-branch

I made a branch from ma master branch called development. The development branch got 2 new commits. Meanwhile the master branch got 1 commit, which was a mistake, then I reverted it and pushed. So far so good. I saw the ahead/behind thingy and I removed the two commits from master (the mistake and the revert one) by resetting HARD to 2 commits back.

Now my metrics on github still shows that development branch is 2 behind although it is not if you look at the commits.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you did the `git reset --hard` on `master`? Sounds like maybe you inadvertently did it on your dev branch, which you had already pushed so it got the two new commits.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I double checked it and I checked it now again. The master ends with commit 5e964d7412 which is also in development and development then has 2 extra commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which metrics on github?
Development is 2 behind what?

If you mean in the graph of forks and development seems to be 2 behind the master branch, you should try the following:

```
git checkout develop  
git rebase master  
git push origin
```

git reset doesn't rewrite history, so the history you have is you did a reset, which is also on github. My guess is that the graph on github uses the history log, but I can't say that for sure.

Comment: Here's the strange thing: Current branch development is up to date. :)

Comment: When you merge develop, after you are done developing, into master everything will be fine.

Comment: Hm. So maybe this shows that develop is 2 ahead of base branch (which is master) and that base branch is 2 behind. I'll be sure when I make another commit. Thank you!

Comment: Actually everything was fine after next commit. Strange. But I'm glad it's fixed.